# selenium keyPress

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm wondering how to use selenium's keyPress function to key in a string, it's easy to key a single character as:

```
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\119") (which  is character 'w');
```

but how can i key in an string say, 'face'? the following code would work but ugly:

```
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\102") (which  is character 'f');
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\97") (which  is character 'a');
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\99") (which  is character 'c');
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\101") (which  is character 'e');
```

and this one wont' work:

```
selenium.keyPress("id=textbox", "\\102\\97\\99\\101")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using "`typeKeys(id=textbox,face)`".

Or if you want to do it in fast you can use `type` and for last char you can use `keyPress` to initiate the the key press event.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the type command? `| type | //input[@name='searchTerms'] | test |`